# All the model values are displayed in the URL, is this normal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, model-binding

I have the following action method:

```
    public ActionResult ViewEmployeeDetails(Employee emp)
    {
        return View(viewName: "EmployeeView", model: emp);
    }
```

This method is to display Employee details. The Employee class has dozens of properties. My problem is that all the property values are displayed in the URL like this:

`http://mymvcapp.com/Employees/ViewEmployeeDetails?DocID=1&EditDate=07%2F25%2F2014%2011%3A00%3A43&IdSerial=AZE&IdNo=09270599&LastName=Abdullayev&FirstName=Mikayil&Patronymic=Cavanshir&Address=Mir%20C%C9%99lal%20k%C3%BC%C3%A7%C9%99si%2059%20K%2C%20451&Address2=Da%C4%9Fl%C4%B1q%20k%C3%BC%C3%A7%C9%99si%2022A&Gender=Male&NationalityID=1&JobDescription=A%C4%B0ST%20Qrup%20MMC&SocialStatus=Servant&SocialCategory=Disabled1&Phone=994503335553&Email=mikayil.abdullayev%40gmail.com&AddressedOfficerID=1&ReceptionMethod=Letter&ApplicationType=Application&SheetCount=14&ReceivedDate=07%2F29%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00&Subject=DegreeOfDisablity&OrganizationID=63&AttachedDocNumber=12121212&AttachedDocDate=07%2F14%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00&Author=Mikola&IsUnderControl=True&IsUnderControlInt=1&PreferredReplyMethod=Written&Status=None&Attachment=System.Byte%5B%5D`

Is it OK to leave it like this or do I have a terrible approach that ended  up in this behavior?

Comment: Can't you pass just the `ID` of the employee to `ViewEmployeeDetails` method and load data using that `ID` and set `Employee` object inside `ViewEmployeeDetails` method ?

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was getting that long url after returning the View. Turns out it happens before that, I mean when I receive the Employee object into the action method, right?

Comment: Yes, in your current approach you are passing all the details since you have `(Employee emp)` (expecting Employee object) in your method. You can just pass the relevant ID of the `Employee`.

Comment: Is `IdNo` unique for `Employee` or do you need both `IdSerial` and `IdNo` both to make `Employee` unique ?

Comment: No, the unique id is the EmpID field. I've actually done the way you suggested in several places, don't know why I chose to do so in this case. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically your get action method would be

```
public ActionResult ViewEmployeeDetails(int ID) 
{
  Employee employee = // get from repository/database based on ID
  return View(employee); // or return employee view model
}
```

so that the friendly url is `http://mymvcapp.com/Employees/ViewEmployeeDetails/1`